# Extension of poly-$\mathbb{Z}$ is poly-$\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

I was studying poly-$\mathbb{Z}$ groups and I found problems trying to prove the following property:

**Let $G$ be a group and $H, K\trianglelefteq G$ such that $K\leq H$. If $G/H$ is poly-$\mathbb{Z}$ and $H/K$ is poly-$\mathbb{Z}$, then $G/K$ is poly-$\mathbb{Z}$**

(poly-$\mathbb{Z}$ means that  there is a chain of subgroups
$\lbrace 1\rbrace=G_0\trianglelefteq G_1\trianglelefteq \dots\trianglelefteq G_n=G$
Satisfying $G_i/G_{i-1}\cong\mathbb{Z}~\forall~i=1,\dots,n$)

Honestly I have no idea where to start, since I can't find a reasonable choice for the chain of subgroups. For example, to prove that a subgroup of a poly-$\mathbb{Z}$ group is poly-$\mathbb{Z}$ or that the cartesian product of poly-$\mathbb{Z}$ groups is poly-$\mathbb{Z}$ its easy since there is only one reasonable choice for the chain of subgroups, but in this case every 'reasonable' idea I have fails at some point.

Any hints or help will be thanked.

Comment: Are you sure that youhave the right statement ? isn't it instead: if $G/K$ and $H/K$ are poly-$\mathbb{Z}$, so is $G/H$ ? Do you have a source for this problem ?

Comment: @GreginGre What you say looks more reasonable than what I wrote, however what I wrote is a property I've seen in a paper, so it must be true too (hopefully).

Comment: Ok, just wanted to be sure. I'm not sure it is relevant to introduce quotients everywhere. May be it is more reasonable to try to prove a more general statement: if $f:G\to Q$ is a surjective group morphism with kernel $N$, and if $Q$ and $N$ are poly-$\mathbb{Z}$, so is $G$. I'm pretty sure the proof works as for soluble groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us prove a more general statement. If $f:G\to Q$ is a surjective morphism with kernel $N$, and if $Q$ and $N$ are poly-$\mathbb{Z}$, so is $G$.

Your original statement will be obtained with the canonical surjective morphism $G/K\to G/H$.

In fact, it works exactly as for the case of solvable groups, so I only sketch the arguments.

Since being poly-$\mathbb{Z}$ is preseved by isomorphism, we may assume wlog that $Q=G/N$ and $f$ is the canonical projection. If $(Q_0,\ldots,Q_n)$ is a suitable filtration of $Q$  (suitable=whose successive quotients are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$), we  can lift it to a succession of subgroups $G_0,\ldots,G_n$ containing $N$ having the same property. Note that that $G_0=N$ since it is the lift of $1_{G/N}$ via the canonical projection. Now complete this family with a suitablefiltration of $N$ and we are done.

Comment: thanks for your help, that was indeed a nice an easy solution

Comment: just one correction, your canical surjective morphism should be $G/K\to G/H$.